# What steps am I missing to make TF2 render a demo as h264?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a demo file created with `record ...` and I wish to convert it to a movie.

I can render as numerous TGA files. I have downloaded and installed latest version of QuickTime Player and rebooted the machine.

In Team Fortress 2 in Windowed mode, I then use the following steps:

- `startmovie e1 h264`  (reports that frames will be captured after clearing the console)
- `playdemo demo` (plays the demo)
- `endmovie`  (closes the movie)

Nothing named along `e1` is now present in the steam folder next to the demo.

From https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Demo_Video_Creation I understand there should be a codec window somewhere, which I do not see.  The documentation for this feature seems to be rather weak and I might have been looking at outdated information.

Platform is Windows 7 x86. What should I try next?

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Demo_Video_Creation) misses one step:

You have to close the console.

Since `startmovie` reports that `frames will be captured after clearing the console` maybe it won't even create a file for a video with no frames.

Next thing to try is to render a `Replay`. I believe it executes the same command. If you manage to render your videos using Replay menu maybe you should try to render your Demo there. Guide on doing that: http://www.teamplayergaming.com/team-fortress-2-a/94958-demos-replay-editor.html.